# nodejs logging network traffic

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I would like to know if there is any way that I can enable Nodejs so It will logs the requests that are made during request-response phase. I have Angular Service hosted and Server Side Rendering enabled on it and I would like to know what requests does the server is making to generate content for response. Those requests are some api requests, some backend services etc but I just need to know what requests are made during rendering html Angular Rendered output.

Comment: Could you give us more information on how your server is setup? are you using ExpressJS? 
Usually, you can log stuff for every request by writing a middleware.

Comment: I don't know what mechanism does Angular Universal is using during fetching required resources to render the html output. In my service layer I'm using `HttpClient` imported from `@angular/common/http`. From browser - server communication there is ExpressJS employed but I'm interesting in the traffic between server and other resources that are requested during generating output from server. I'm not interested in traffic between browser and server because it is very easy to monitoring using Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: I misunderstood your use case. You can write an HttpInterceptor to log every request https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor. You can find an example in this article: https://scotch.io/@vigneshsithirai/angular-6-7-http-client-interceptor-with-error-handling

Answer (score 0):

You can use grackle_tracking library https://www.getgrackle.com/analytics_and_tracking

It let's you track all traffic to the console and to your database. In addition it also tracks uncaught and caught errors by your application.